# Can we use an assert statement inside a function in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

I wrote a simple recursive fibonacci program that works fine without an assert statement, but when I add an assert statement, even with various permutations of parentheses, spaces, and double semicolons, I keep getting a syntax error during compilation.

Working function:

```
let rec fib n =

if n = 1
then 1
else
n*(fib (n-1))
```

Not working:

```
let rec fib n =

assert (n>=0)

if n = 1
then 1
else
n*(fib (n-1))
```

Any thoughts appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Extra spaces do not affect the semantics of OCaml programs. There are also no statements per se in OCaml - everything is an expression. To evaluate two expressions in a sequence you may use the semicolon, e.g.,

```
print_endline "Hello";
assert (1 > 2);
print_endline "World";
```

You can also use `let .. in ..` to chain expressions, especially, if you need to the expression values, e.g.,

```
let x = 1 + 2 in
let y = 3 + 4 in
Format.printf "%d + %d = %d\n" x y (x + y)
```

Going back to your example, it should be

```
let rec fib n =
  assert (n >= 0);
  if n = 1 then 1
  else n * fib (n - 1)
```

P.S. The double semicolons are not really a part of the language but a special input sequence to be used in the interactive toplevel.

Answer (score 0):

You have two expressions: `assert (n >= 0)` and `if ... then ... else ...`. If you want the two expressions to be evaluated in sequence (which you do), you need to separate them with a semicolon:

```
let rec fib n =
  assert (n >= 0);
  if n = 1 then 1
  else n * fib (n - 1);;
val fib : int -> int = <fun>
# fib 3;;
- : int = 6
# fib (-3);;
Exception: Assert_failure ("//toplevel//", 2, 4).
```